# Highlighting the shortest path in a Networkx graph

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I have a network of people. I can display how they are connected by creating a directed graph using Networkx.

Here is a code sample:

```
edges = edglist
nodes = nodelist
dg.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)
#print dg.nodes()
print nx.shortest_path(dg, source='Freda', target='Levi', weight=None)
nx.draw(dg)
plt.savefig("path.png")
```

Which produces:
[image: connections graph]

I can also calculate a shortest path between two nodes. However what I am stuck on is how to highlight this 'shortest path'. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. BTW, I am a newbie

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos,node_color='k')
# draw path in red
path = nx.shortest_path(G,source=14,target=16)
path_edges = list(zip(path,path[1:]))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=path,node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=path_edges,edge_color='r',width=10)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: hH, so basically the original graph is drawn and then the shortest past is drawn on top of that? So the red dots actually go on top of the black dots? Also my graph is directed, can the direction be shown with an arrow?

Comment: Yes that is the concept.  You can avoid "double" drawing of the nodes and edges by skipping the nx.draw() call and specifically stating which nodes and edges to draw.  Unfortunately there is no arrow drawing with NetworkX+Matplotlib.

Comment: @Aric can you please let me know how to show labels of the shortest path

Answer (score 3):

you should add  a set() `path_edges = set(path_edges)`after your zip() to get the shortest path coloration work

Comment: Actually the OP doesn't have any zip in his code. If you meant to add information to Aric's answer, consider turning your answer into a comment